# Use member function for `std::thread` with `std::ref(*this)` fails to compile

Tags: c++, gcc, c++14, standards-compliance

I use the following minimal example to reproduce the compiler error I get when I try to make a thread that calls a non-static-member function to do its work:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
class Worker
{
public:
  Worker() : m_worker(&Worker::doWork, std::ref(*this), 1)
  {}
  std::thread m_worker;

  void doWork(int a) { std::cout << a << std::endl; }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  Worker k;
}
```

When using gcc4.8-gcc5.1 this fails to compile with the following reason:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/thread:39:0,

from /tmp/gcc-explorer-compiler115614-69-rgangs/example.cpp:1:

/usr/include/c++/4.8/functional: In instantiation of 'struct std::_Bind_simple<std::_Mem_fn<void (Worker::*)(int)>(std::reference_wrapper<Worker>, int)>':

/usr/include/c++/4.8/thread:137:47: required from 'std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (Worker::*)(int); _Args = {std::reference_wrapper<Worker>, int}]'

7 : required from here

/usr/include/c++/4.8/functional:1697:61: error: no type named 'type' in 'class std::result_of<std::_Mem_fn<void (Worker::*)(int)>(std::reference_wrapper<Worker>, int)>'

typedef typename result_of<_Callable(_Args...)>::type result_type;

^

/usr/include/c++/4.8/functional:1727:9: error: no type named 'type' in 'class std::result_of<std::_Mem_fn<void (Worker::*)(int)>(std::reference_wrapper<Worker>, int)>'

_M_invoke(_Index_tuple<_Indices...>)

^

Compilation failed
```

Clang, on the other hand seems to compile this code just fine. Who is correct here and is this a bug in gcc (with open tickets?)?

---

**EDIT:** When using `m_worker(&Worker::doWork, this, 1)` to initialize the thread, gcc compiles this just fine. So, is it legal to use `std::ref(*this)` in this case? I guess any `std::ref()`, to be more general.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit that exactly makes the difference, thank you, now an answer to why this makes a difference and if it is legal would be cool

Comment: See https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2219 This will be fixed some day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `thread` constructor call relies on the following semantics:

> `[C++14: 30.3.1.2/3]:` *Requires:* `F` and each `Ti` in `Args` shall satisfy the *MoveConstructible* requirements. *INVOKE* `(`*DECAY_COPY* `( std::forward<F>(f)),` *DECAY_COPY* `(std::forward<Args>(args))...)` (20.9.2) shall be a valid expression.

And `INVOKE` is defined thus:

> `[C++14: 20.9.2/1]:` Define *INVOKE* `(f, t1, t2, ..., tN)` as follows:
>
> - `(t1.*f)(t2, ..., tN)` when `f` is a pointer to a member function of a class `T` and `t1` is an object of type `T` or a reference to an object of type `T` or a reference to an object of a type derived from `T`;
> - `((*t1).*f)(t2, ..., tN)` when `f` is a pointer to a member function of a class `T` and `t1` is not one of the types described in the previous item;
> - `t1.*f` when `N == 1` and `f` is a pointer to member data of a class `T` and `t1` is an object of type `T` or a reference to an object of type `T` or a reference to an object of a type derived from `T`;
> - `(*t1).*f` when `N == 1` and `f` is a pointer to member data of a class `T` and `t1` is not one of the types described in the previous item;
> - `f(t1, t2, ..., tN)` in all other cases.

As you can see, there is no provision here for `std::reference_wrapper<Worker>`, which is what `std::ref(*this)` gives you. Certainly nothing in the decay rules helps (`[C++14: 30.2.6/1]`).

Clang is actually jumping the gun a little here, seemingly allowing this because it is going to be standard-compliant one day thanks to our very own [Jonathan Wakely](https://stackoverflow.com/users/981959/jonathan-wakely) filing [Library Working Group issue #2219](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2219). But, for now, it's not.

Anyway, this whole thing is moot. There is no need to write this code. Just write this:

```
Worker() : m_worker(&Worker::doWork, this, 1)
```

Comment: Yeah `ref()` is for the arguments, not the callable. Given that you can always take a pointer to the callable anytime you could take a reference anyway, probably doesn't make sense to overcomplicate the language to allow for that sort of thing.

Comment: ^ My thoughts too, basically

Comment: Ha, see Praetorian's [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31417389/use-member-function-for-stdthread-with-stdrefthis-fails-to-compile/31417550?noredirect=1#comment50808043_31417389) Guess it's going in.

Comment: @Barry: Ace! Have incorporated that.